# two eyes and a mouth

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> two eyes and a mouth
> another north or south
> in years we have not moved
> yet we are charged with something to prove
>
> when we are off duty
> our mouth stays open
> when we are on
> our mouth is full
>
> our eyes don't see
> and rather infrequently
> you stab us there
> and we amplify our stare
>
> if you take us off our post
> and reach behind our back
> you may not feel great
> as the board told you to wait

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer

> An electrical outlet

two eyes and a mouth
another north or south
in years we have not moved
yet we are charged with something to prove

> They usually, these days, are three-pronged, and resemble eyes and a mouth.  They usually come in pairs, one on top of the other

when we are off duty
our mouth stays open
when we are on
our mouth is full

> When off duty, nothing is plugged in, so their mouths are empty.  The mouth is full when something is plugged in

our eyes don't see
and rather infrequently
you stab us there
and we amplify our stare

> The prongs of a plug "stab" them in the eyes.  The stare is amplified, as electricity is now flowing

if you take us off our post
and reach behind our back
you may not feel great
as the board told you to wait

> Removing an electrical outlet, and reaching behind will give you a nasty shock.

Answer (score 0):

is it

> helium atom

one nucleus mouth two electrons eye.

```
two eyes and a mouth
another north or south
in years we have not moved
yet we are charged with something to prove
```

> Nucleus is positively charged , and electrons -ve . Nucleus does not move .rotation of electrons create magentic effect of N pole and south pole.

```
when we are off duty
our mouth stays open
when we are on
our mouth is full
```

> Nucleus alone attracts -ve so open . But helium is stable nobel gas with 2e-s in the orbit .

```
our eyes don't see
and rather infrequently
you stab us there
and we amplify our stare
```

> electrons getting exiceted to next level.

Comment: I assume you are going to add more explanation?